# How to chain API requests in useEffect() with custom hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

- I'm trying to fetch a user's latitude and longitude coordinates and then using those coordinates make a search request inside of useEffect()
- `location` is always `null` when `useResults`
  executes and this is the problem
- `useResults` and `fetchLocation` both work individually but I'm having trouble chaining them together
- Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks

###### My Code (I'm trying to do something like this)

```
    const [fetchLocation, location, message] = useLocation()
    const [fetchResults, searchResults, isSearchError] = useResults()

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchLocation()                    // get user longitude and latitude, set longitude and latitude data into "location"
        useResults({
             location.coords.longitude, 
             location.coords.latitude })   // feed longitude and latitude data into useResults
    }, [])
```

###### useResults.js

```
const useResults = () => {
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([])
    const [isSearchError, setIsSearchError] = useState(false)

    const fetchResults = async (
        searchTerm,
        { latitude, longitude }
    ) => {
        try {
            // get search data
            const response = await yelpAPI.get("/search", {
                params: {
                    limit: 50,
                    term: searchTerm,
                    latitude,
                    longitude
                }
            })
            // set search data
            setSearchResults(response.data.businesses)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            console.log("Something went wrong in useResults.js")
            setIsSearchError(true)
        }
    }

    return [fetchResults, searchResults, isSearchError]
}
```

###### useLocation.js

```
const useLocation = () => {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(null)
    const [message, setMessage] = useState(
        "Fetching user location data"
    )

    const fetchLocation = async () => {
        try {
            let { status } =
                await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync()

            if (status !== "granted") {
                setErrorMsg(
                    "Permission to access location was denied"
                )
                return
            }
            // get user location data
            let locationData = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync(
                {}
            )
            setMessage(null)
            // set user location data
            setLocation(locationData)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            setMessage("Fetching user location failed")
        }
    }

    return [fetchLocation, location, message]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two useEffect. one is gonna run on mount:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLocation()                    // get user longitude and latitude, set longitude and latitude data into "location"
  }, [])
```

and one that is gonna run when the location is fetched & has a value:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (location)
      fetchResults({location.coords.longitude, 
        location.coords.latitude})                    // get user longitude and latitude, set longitude and latitude data into "location"
  }, [location])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `fetchLocation` is updating the hook's state, it looks like these should be broken up into separate `useEffect` calls.  The first would happen once (fetch the location), the second would happen when the location changes.  Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchLocation();
}, []); // empty dependency array, happens once when the component loads

useEffect(() => {
    useResults({
         location.coords.longitude, 
         location.coords.latitude
    });
}, [location]); // happens any time the location changes, which *should* only be once
```

---

Another alternative could be if `fetchLocation` also *returns* its results, not just updates state.  For example:

```
setMessage(null);
// set user location data
setLocation(locationData);
return locationData; // <-- here
```

Then, while state is still updated for components to use, anything which immediately depends on the values can simply await the results.  Something like:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const tempLoc = await fetchLocation();
    useResults({
         tempLoc.coords.longitude, 
         tempLoc.coords.latitude
    });
}, []);
```

That way you wouldn't be re-rendering as many times and the latter operation is just using the returned results instead of the updated state.